# Hadoop HDFS start up fails requires formatting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a multi-node standalone hadoop cluster for HDFS. I am able to load data to HDFS, however everytime I reboot my computer and start the cluster by `start-dfs.sh`, I don't see the dashboard until I perform `hdfs namenode -format` which erases all my data.
How do I start hadoop cluster without having to go through `hdfs namenode -format`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to shutdown hdfs and the namenode cleanly (stop-dfs) before you shutdown your computer. Otherwise, you can corrupt the namenode, causing you to need to format to get back to a clean state